# Pig matches not matching digits

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I've spent hours bashing my head over this. The Pig docs say that it uses Java's regex but when I try the same thing in Java with the same REGEX it works as expected.

I have this data:

```
id=6139406,ci=6139407,corr_id_=8c0c7700f95aa
id=6139106,ci=6139107,corr_id_=0e89749_df942a
id=6139906,ci=6139907,corr_id_=09ea6&f6cf94cb
id=6141100,ci=6141101,corr_id_=42ab372dfacd5
id=6141100,ci=6141101,corr_id_=asssddsA01
```

And this simple Pig trying to filter based on ids that are alphanumeric;

```
A = LOAD 'users.dat' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:chararray, tid:chararray, corr_id:chararray); -- loading data

B = FILTER A BY ($2 matches 'corr_id_=[a-zA-Z0-9]*'); 
DUMP B;
```

It all works fine until I try to enter the numeric portion of the regex. As soon as I put 0-9 or \d both of which are valid in Java it fails to make a match.

What am I missing here?

Comment: No I am trying to filter out the records that have special characters. The problem is as soon as I add "0-9" or "\d" the regex fails. Also the demo isn't helpful, I can put the same regex in any Java regex parser and they all resolve correctly. This is a pig specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is `'.*expr.*'`. In your case since the beginning of the string is fixed, you'll only need the .* at the end.

```
B = FILTER A BY ($2 matches '(corr_id_=[a-zA-Z0-9]).*');
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Every record is returned, even the one with special characters.. I'd tried this already. Thanks regardless.

Comment: Unfortunately I have, this returns 5 empty rows in the output.